# Jsfiddle - strange characters on UI

Tags: css, google-chrome, text, character-encoding, jsfiddle

what's the solution for this kind of problem (weird characters) that suddenly appeared for me on jsfiddle.net? This started a few weeks ago. Any similar experiences?

[image: strange characters]

[image: weird characters]

### Update 1

It works perfectly well in IE9 and FF19.0.2. Only on Chrome 26 I have these characters.
And there's more. If I disable font-styling with chrome developer tools, these strange characters became normal.

### Update 2

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

this css declaration is the problem. Reminder: I'm using Chrome 29.0.1547.57 m

### Update 3

@user2923075 reminded me that this question exist and I had to update it again.
At the time of this question I was installing font families in windows and some helvetica family was causing this. I deleted it and everything was ok. But it seems that there isn't only one source for this problem as @user2923075 pointed out with his Mac experience. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: If you're on a Mac with Safari or Chrome - RESTART your computer. Apple had an update resent on the javascript framework, and you need a restart to enforce this update to activate. My problem was related to that my OSX hadn't been restarted for 3 months (you know.. Mac, OSX, never crash etc, etc) Do the restart and it most lightly will fix the problem.

> You will see this alot also if you use Safari 6.x on a Mac. Switching
>   to Western ISO Latin 1 or Unicode UTF-8 - or any other text encoding
>   in the Safari Advanced Options won't help. Seams like you need to
>   switch to another browser like Firefox. That will fix it. Problem
>   shows up on sites like jsfiddle.net, daniweb.com and other.

Comment: so, there isn't only one source for this problem. This bit of css that I added in my question before solved the issue. But this is not ok. And I found that one font installed on my pc was causing that too (some helvetica family as I remember). At the time of the question I was a window user, now I'm in a ubuntu full time and the problem never happened again. But thanks to add your experience with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a CSS issue if it was you would see it more and more. This is a browser issue.

Google Chrome automatically matches system fonts with the appropriate language encoding. As long as the appropriate fonts for each language are installed, Chrome will probably be able to interpret a properly encoded page.

If you do not see the content, you need to install the correct font as listed on the individual By Language pages.

> Change Encoding (Windows 7)
>
> Click the settings (wrench) icon after the URL address bar and select
>   Tools → Encoding to view the current encoding.. If necessary switch
>   from Unicode (UTF-8) or Western (ISO Latin 1) to an appropriate
>   encoding. In some cases you may need to scroll to the end of the menu.
>   If there is more than one option per script, select one until the page
>   displays properly. AFTER you leave the site, you may need to switch
>   your browser back to your original setting.
>   \